# mySQL 'Stop Slave' on Server Reboot

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Is there a way in mySQL to issue a 'stop slave' command when the server is rebooted to prevent the replication from getting out of sync? I haven't been able to find anything definitive on this.

Comment: No reason it couldn't be worked into the init script or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [skip-slave-start](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_skip-slave-start).

Hope this helps.

Cheers